# Gem installed from github sources not shown in `gem list`

Tags: ruby, git, github, rubygems

I trying to install some gem from github sources, it is installed succesfully, but after that it is not shown in `gem list` output and cannot be required.

My gem is in private repo, but I can reproduce those steps on random public repo.
For example:

1. I create Gemfile with content:

> ```
> source 'http://rubygems.org'
> gem 'http_parser.rb', git: 'https://github.com/tmm1/http_parser.rb.git'
> ```

2. I call `bundle install` and it's output is:

> ```
> Fetching https://github.com/tmm1/http_parser.rb.git
> Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
> Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
> Resolving dependencies...
> Using http_parser.rb 0.6.0 from https://github.com/tmm1/http_parser.rb.git (at master@10dd2ed)
> Using bundler 1.11.2
> Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
> Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
> ```

3. After that I call `gem list | grep http` and get nothing. Also I cannot call `require "http/parser"` in my code, it cannot be found.

What did I done wrong?

Comment: Try `bundle exec gem list` (or `bundle list`). In your code, you probably have to call `require 'rubygems'` and `require 'bundler/setup'` before you can `require 'http/parser'`. See http://bundler.io/bundler_setup.html for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @stefan,
`require 'bundler/setup'`
solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Or for running the irb you can use

```
bundle exec irb
```

instead of

```
irb
```